# How to parse this date/time in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, datetime, localdatetime

I have this NMEA timestamp: `120722202122` and I want to parse it.

I tried

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun main() {
   println(LocalDateTime.parse("120722202122", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("DDMMyyHHmmss")))
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/oZ8v4gB-M)</sup>

but I get an Exception:

> ```
> Conflict found: Field MonthOfYear 1 differs from MonthOfYear 7 derived from 2022-01-12
> ```

I don't know what the Exception wants to tell me or what my pattern should look like.

Comment: Please remember to specify *desired result*.  Your string, `120722202122`, is not so easy to read that this is self evident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you've probably meant the *day of the month* `d`, not the *day of the year* `D`.

In your pattern, you've specified the day of the year `DD`, and therefore the next part `MM` representing the *month* happens to be redundant. And exception-message says that the *month* you've specified conflicts with the provided *day of the year*. Because the `12th` *day of the year* falls on the *first month*, not on the `7th`, and therefore string `"1207..."` can't be resolved into a valid date-time.

If you need the *day of the month*, the correct pattern would be `"ddMMyyHHmmss"`.

With the *day of the year*, you can use pattern `"DyyHHmmss"` (but the string from your example doesn't match it).

[*A link to Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/Dkqk7xAWO)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [DateTimeFormatter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) "DD" stands for day of year. You want day of month, which is "dd".